# Not able to create folder on desktop in my windows 8 sony vaio laptop

Tags: windows-8

Since last one month, I am not able to create a new folder on my desktop. I am using a Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 8.1 installed. Below is the error which I am getting.

"Destination folder access denied. Desktop shows files, folders, program shortcuts and other items on the desktop".

[image: What I see]

I am frustrated with this as I am not able fix this since a long time. How do I fix this issue, are there any setting changes required?

Comment: In future please let a moderator or the community migrate your question between Stack Exchange sites rather than reposting them.  Additionally if you sign in using the same credentials you used for [so] then you should be able to link your accounts.

Comment: I would check the permissions on the desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing ownership permissions of Desktop. Use following method.

1. Open Elevated *Command Prompt* (Run as Admin)
2. Type following command

   ```
   C:\> takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y
   ```

   Replace  with the full path of the folder location. Usually Desktop is Located at `C:\Users\<user-name>\Desktop` replace  with the your username.
3. To assign Control Permissions use following command

   ```
   C:\> icacls <foldername> /grant <user-name>:F /T
   ```
4. Now try creating folder on Desktop.

You can also try [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/destination-folder-access-denied/6bd58749-31da-40bd-8065-e66ab264c118) and method 3 given [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/67717-take-ownership-file.html) to manually change ownership.

Hope this helps.